# Combining bigfoot with fnpct breaks footnote counter

Tags: counters, bigfoot, fnpct

When combining `bigfoot` and `fnpct` in accordance to the packages' documentation, `\setcounter` does not work anymore for default footnotes:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{fnpct} %working without this line
\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

\begin{document}
\footnote{Test}
\footnote{Test}

\footnoteA{Test}
\footnoteA{Test}

\setcounter{footnote}{10}
\setcounter{footnoteA}{10}

\footnote{Test}
\footnote{Test}

\footnoteA{Test}
\footnoteA{Test}
\end{document}
```

What can be done to get back the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

While writing I suddenly realized, that when loading `fnpct` one has to use the counter `footnotedefault` instead of `footnote`. However, without loading `fnpct` `footnotedefault` does not work.

Confusing ...

Comment: It's been a while but I *think* this is a somewhat known and documented issue. Have you checked the section about `bigfoot` in `fnpct`'s manual?

Comment: Well, you find the line `\def\p@footnotedefault{\p@footnote}%` in the documentation of `bigfoot`, but I can find no hint whatsoever describing this interaction problem.

Comment: I wasn't talking about bigfoot's manual

Comment: I am sorry, but there is no hint in `fnpct`'s manual either.